# Python Gitlab. How can I create a new directory in a project

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab

I want to create a new directory using python code. I did not find such an option in the documentation for the library. Is it possible to do this? Or is it possible via api?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an empty Directory! And No need to create directory, you should just specify complete path + file-name and Gitlab automatically create parent directories.
Example:

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(baseURL, ACCESS_TOKEN)
project = gl.projects.get(PROJECT_PATH)
project.files.create(
    {
        "file_path": directory_name + "/" + file_name,
        "branch": branch_name,
        "content": "data to be written",
        "encoding": "text"'
        "commit_message": f"Create {file_name} file",
    }
```

In the end, if you have to create one, you can create a dummy file and name it ".gitkeep" to have a clean directory.

Answer (score -1):

From a project's files page, click the '+' button to the right of the branch selector. Choose 'New directory' from the dropdown. In the new directory dialog enter a directory name, a commit message and choose the target branch. Click 'Create directory' to finish. I had a different computer than some tutorials, so that may also be the problem.

https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/02/10/feature-highlight-create-files-and-directories-from-files-page/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).